# Confused about onTap

Tags: android

I'm a bit confused about the onTap method(s) and how they work with ItemizedOverlay. I want the user to tap on the map and then I place an OverlayItem (icon) where they tapped. Then I want them to tap that OverlayItem again to confirm the location.

I can add the OverlayItem to the map no problems by overriding

```
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)
```

But then I want to capture the user tapping on that item by overriding

```
protected boolean onTap(int i)
```

The trouble is, when I override BOTH of these methods, the second method is never executed when I tap my icon item.

I've followed all the examples but I'm still stuck. Could someone give me an idea what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks

Comment: Just some additional info, if I do NOT implement the first method, and instead manually add my icon somewhere via code (which isn't very interactive) I can tap the icon and then display a dialog that asks 'do you want to use this location', but ovbiously this isn't much use because I need the first method to allow the user to change the selected location

Comment: Oh just found this which I'm hoping will help http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/91d4e6d87151a0e1/fceaec7c7e3850e8?show_docid=fceaec7c7e3850e8#

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. The super.onTap seems to be the thing I was missing. These are my methods, so you see the 'GeoPoint' version of onTap is the main entry point, and it works! The link I posted was also very helpful.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
        // If it was the parent that was tapped, do nothing
        if(super.onTap(p, mapView)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            lastClickedLocation = p;
            mapView.getController().animateTo(lastClickedLocation);                                 
            if(markerItem == null) {
                markerItem = new OverlayItem(lastClickedLocation, "", "");
                items.add(markerItem);
            }
            else {
                items.remove(markerItem);
                markerItem = new OverlayItem(lastClickedLocation, "", "");
                items.add(markerItem);
            }
            Utils.alert(parent.getApplicationContext(), parent.getResources().getString(R.string.tapAgainToConfirm));
            populate();
            return true;
        }           
    }

    /**
     * Override the onTap(index) method
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i) {
        parent.confirmLocation(items.get(i));
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but I think it will work:

Try chaining to the superclass from the `GeoPoint`-flavored `onTap()`. That should give you the default processing of calling the index-flavored `onTap()`. Override that method to find out when the user taps on an existing marker and return `true` to indicate you handled the event. Back in the `GeoPoint`-flavored `onTap()`, if `super.onTap()` returns `true`, that means the event was handled by somebody (such as you). Therefore, if it is `false`, add a marker at the supplied `GeoPoint`.